# opencv remap to a different size image

Tags: c++, opencv, remap

Can I use remap to map one image into another image with a different size?

for example assume that I want to map all pixels from image one (with size a,b) that x+y<100 into a new image and the size of new image should be 2a+b, 2b+a.

Comment: yes, you can. you need to create a mapping function map.create(newimage.size(), CV_32FC1); and populate it. example here, check result 2 with a new size: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[remap](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap) is more suited for geometical transformations of image. If you are aiming for image resizing only [imresize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) is a better option for image resizing images. In your case your can simply write

`resize(source_Img, destination_Img, Size(2a+b,2b+a), 0, 0, interpolation);`

Comment: "I want to map all pixels from image one (with size a,b) that x+y<100" it looks like he wants to map a triangle area to a rectangle, so..

Comment: sorry! misunderstood the question.Thanks for clearification.If thats the case then I second your comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that if you provide map image of required size. See documentation of [remap](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap).

Is there any reason that you can't use [resize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) function for that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I want to remap an image to another one (geometric transformation) and the result is not the same as input image. For example converting a panoramic image to cubeface images (http://www.tiempo-digital.com/en/software/tocube/tocube.html )